# Jquery Drag All item at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag

Here is my working code `[JsFiddle]`[1](http://jsfiddle.net/syedsaadabbasi/9dq0os2e/1/). I want to drag all image with `.select` class at once, but currently it is dragging a single element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use a container for those files, so that you actually drag one element. Then accept this element in container, and then after drop handle the situation as you like.

Try [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dq0os2e/7/) (modified yours), here's an extract from JS:

```
$("#OriginalContainer .ImageWrapper").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        refreshPositions: true,
        drag: function (event, ui) {
                ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
                ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
        }
        });
      $("#DestinationContainer").droppable({
       accept: "#OriginalContainer .ImageWrapper",
       drop: function (event, ui) {

        console.log(ui.draggable); $(ui.draggable).find('.selected').addClass("dropped").removeClass('selected');
             $("#DestinationContainer").append($(ui.draggable).find('.selected'));
        }
        });
```